# Oracle Query with Partision, Order and Bucketing

Tags: oracle, counting, rank

Sample Data:

```
Customer ID  Transaction Date  Code  Expected Bucketing
-----------  ----------------  ----  ----
          1    1/1/2015        254      1
          1    1/2/2015        253      1
          1    1/13/2015       271      1
          1    1/14/2015       271      1
          1    2/1/2015        254      2
          1    2/12/2015       253      2
          1    2/13/2015       271      2
          1    3/1/2015        254      3
          1    3/12/2015       253      3
          1    3/13/2015       271      3
          2    1/1/2015        254      1
          2    1/2/2015        253      1
          2    1/13/2015       271      1
          2    1/14/2015       271      1
          2    2/1/2015        254      2
          2    2/12/2015       253      2
          2    2/13/2015       271      2
```

I want to Partision by "Customer ID" and sort by "Transaction Date"
Everytime the first record starts with transaction code 254.
I have to start counting first time i found 254 (1) till is find the next 254 (then count as 2).
The 4th field is what i am trying to achieve.

Can someone help me with this in Oracle query to get data like field 4 above

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution **1** - self-join query, where one of subqueries is data with code=254, second is rest.
These subqueries are next joined and row numbers from first are assigned to second part:

```
with t1 as (
    select cid, tdate td1, code, 
        lead(tdate) over (partition by cid order by tdate) td2,
        row_number() over (partition by cid order by tdate) rn
      from test where code=254),
  t2 as (select cid, tdate, code from test where code<>254)
select t2.cid, t2.tdate, t2.code, t1.rn from t1 
  join t2 on t1.cid = t2.cid 
         and t2.tdate between nvl(t1.td1, t2.tdate) and nvl(t1.td2, t2.tdate)
union all 
select cid, td1, code, rn from t1 order by cid, tdate
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/656f4/1)

---

Solution **2** - recursive query, available from Oracle version 11g:

```
with t as (select cid, tdate, code, 
  row_number() over (partition by cid order by tdate) rn from test),
u (cid, td, cd, rn, x) as (
  select cid, tdate, code, rn, 1 from t where rn=1
  union all
  select t.cid, t.tdate, t.code, t.rn, decode(t.code, 254, u.x+1, u.x)
    from u join t on t.cid = u.cid and t.rn = u.rn+1 )
select cid, td, cd, x from u order by cid, td
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/656f4/2)

---

Both solutions produced desired output and in both I assumed that row with code=254 is first in set for each customer, like in your example.

Useful links: [function lead()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm), function [row_number()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm), [recursive queries](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_recursive_subquery_factoring_with_clause.htm) and last but not least [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).